# Compromised Ubuntu VPS

Tags: ubuntu, vps

for last two days I have problems with my VPS server for website. This server has been attacking with TCP Syn Flood Attack for two days and in same time, which of course lead to disconnect of this server from provider side.

Yesterday I was looking for the problem, and try all of these:

- Update firewall settings
- Update user password
- Look for communications on port (well, obviously the attack wasn't in charge)
- Look for rootkit
- Look in /tmp for malicous code
- Look for sleeping processes and daemons (ps faxu) and checked everythingin list

But nothing was found and midnight the attack began again... Got now helpless and know for what to look more. Any ideas?

The mentioned website is custom solution based on framework, so there is no thing like wrong plugin or so. The OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: Set up the VPS from scratch and restore the website from a backup.